# Div is getting clipped in IE7...stumped

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have little notification divs that should appear above the navigation. I tried other solutions from different posts (like giving it's parent a z-index) but I can't get it to work.

[image: Safari Screenshot]
[image: IE7 Screenshot]

They are clipping with IE 7. Any ideas of what i'm doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/SkinnyGeek1010/7rguC/  
[Live link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1407764/www/stackoverflow/Menu-Notification-Bar/index.html)

Comment: `progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f9f9f9', endColorstr='#f0f0f0',GradientType=0)` kills your effect. Try to apply it not to the `li`, but to the wrapper of the `li`'s content. And move your `div` with numbers out of this wrapper.

Comment: Wow thanks, it works! Your so smart! =D
Don't you want to post that below so you get some points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f9f9f9', endColorstr='#f0f0f0',GradientType=0)` kills your effect (who knows what IE is doing there).

Try to apply it not to the `li`, but to the wrapper of the `li`'s content. And move your `div` with numbers out of this wrapper.